# Mathematica: Integration of Bessel Function & Exponent Function & Trigonometric Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration

I have an integral with the form

```
Int[k_]:=Integrate[Exp[-x]xSin[x]BesselJ[0,k*x],{x,0,10}]
```

where `BesselJ[0,kr]` is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Now i can't get the directly answer from Mathematica..

I want to get the curve of `Int[k]`, maybe a approximate is also acceptable..What can I do then?

Comment: Are you expecting a closed form result? Why do you think the function has an anti-derivative?

Comment: A closed result is also acceptable.. Just I have to get the result from the function..Anyway I am not sure whether it has the direct answer or not.

Comment: Using `I[k_]=...` is problematic because `I` is a system function for `Sqrt[-1]`.  The convention is to use lower case initial character for user-defined functions to avoid conflict with built-in functions, i.e. `int[k_]=...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function doesn't have an antiderivative, your best bet is to numerically integrate. Example:

```
Int[k_] := NIntegrate[Exp[-x] x Sin[x] BesselJ[0, k x], {x, 0, 10}]
Plot[Int[k], {k, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

PS: I have edited your question, as you had some typos. You cannot use `I` as the symbol (it messes the complex `i`), and also when defining a function have to use `:=` instead of `=`.

Comment: YES..Sorry for the careless..AHA~~

Answer (score 1):

Even setting the constants to unity, Mathematica cannot find a formula for the integral.  I.e.

```
a = b = k = d = 1;

Integrate[(a r Exp[-r] - b r Sin[k (r - d)] Exp[-r]) BesselJ[0, k r], r]
```

The integral is returned unchanged.

Simplifying things a bit shows some progress, returning a formula.

```
Integrate[Sin[k (r - d)] BesselJ[0, k r], r]
```

But adding back in one of the exponents throws it again.

```
Integrate[Sin[k (r - d)] Exp[-r] BesselJ[0, k r], r]
```

Comment: The question has been modified .. could U have a look at again?can I get a curve of I[k]?